# Wordpress blogging with org2blog, "Error during request: 400"

Tags: org-mode, gnutls

I used to use [org2blog](https://github.com/org2blog/org2blog) to post my wordpress posts.

However, a few months ago, it suddenly stopped to work: when I tried to log in with `org2blog/wp-login` I had an

> "Error during request: 400"

error.

I stayed a long time without being able to fix the problem... What is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I recently find [this issue post](https://github.com/org2blog/org2blog/issues/264)

The fix is to add:

```
(setq gnutls-algorithm-priority "NORMAL:-VERS-TLS1.3")
```

(I am running under Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) with Emacs 26.1)